# Content Provider fault

Tags: android, service, android-contentprovider

In my app I use a content provider. As you know the content provider is the middle man between the client and `SQLite`. In my case I retrieve the data from a server using volley,store them in `SQLite`, and finally read them using the `ContentResolver` object and the `LoaderManager` interface(which has onCreateLoader,onLoadFinished,onLoaderReset). I also use a service, as I want to run my webservice, when the app is closed.

**MyService**

```
  public class MyService extends IntentService {
  private final String LOG_TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();


  public MyService() {
    super("My Service");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    updateCityList();
  }
  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }
  public void updateCityList() {

    cityList.clear();

    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    JsonArrayRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, 
   API.API_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            //hidePD();

            // Parse json data.
            // Declare the json objects that we need and then for loop through the children array.
            // Do the json parse in a try catch block to catch the exceptions
            try {

                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject post = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    MyCity item = new MyCity();
                    item.setName(post.getString("title"));
                    item.setImage(API.IMAGE_URL + post.getString("image"));
                    ContentValues imageValues = new ContentValues();

                    imageValues.put(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry._ID, post.getString("id"));
                    imageValues.put(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.COLUMN_NAME, post.getString("title"));
                    imageValues.put(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.COLUMN_ICON, post.getString("image"));

                    getContentResolver().insert(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.CONTENT_URI, imageValues);
                    cityList.add(item);

                    cityList.add(item);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Update list by notifying the adapter of changes
            myCityAdpapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            //hidePD();
        }
    });
    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
static public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(sendIntent);
    }
   }
}
```

**MainActivityFragment**

```
 public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment implements    

 LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
 static public ArrayList<MyCity> cityList;
 public String [] MY_CITY_PROJECTIONS = {MyCityContract.MyCityEntry._ID,
        MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.COLUMN_NAME,
        MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.COLUMN_ICON};
private static final String LOG_TAG =    
MainActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();
public static MyCityAdpapter myCityAdpapter;
private static final int CURSOR_LOADER_ID = 0;
private GridView mGridView;

public MainActivityFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.refresh, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    // inflate fragment_main layout
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity, container, false);

    cityList = new ArrayList<>();

    // initialize our FlavorAdapter
    myCityAdpapter = new MyCityAdpapter(getActivity(), null, 0, CURSOR_LOADER_ID);
    // initialize mGridView to the GridView in fragment_main.xml
    mGridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.flavors_grid);
    // set mGridView adapter to our CursorAdapter
    mGridView.setAdapter(myCityAdpapter);
    Cursor c =
            getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{MyCityContract.MyCityEntry._ID},
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);
    if (c.getCount() == 0){
        updateCityData();
    }
    // initialize loader
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(CURSOR_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    return rootView;

}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args){
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
            MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            MY_CITY_PROJECTIONS,
            null,
            null,
            null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    myCityAdpapter.swapCursor(data);
}


@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader){
    myCityAdpapter.swapCursor(null);
}

public void updateCityData() {

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyService.AlarmReceiver.class);


    //Wrap in a pending intent which only fires once.
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0,alarmIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);//getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    //Set the AlarmManager to wake up the system.
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, pi);
    }
 }
```

I just setup an alarm manager to make my service run after 5 seconds. This is just for testing really. Anyway,here is my problem. When I launch the app for the first time,nothing in shown in my screen. When I exit though,and launch it again,I can see all the images in my gridview. Why is this happening? To make more clear

When I launch the app for the first time:

```
10-16 12:07:00.799 16685-16685/theo.testing.androidcustomloaders D/ContentValues: [{"id":"15","title":"The Gate of Larissa","image":"larissa17.png"},{"id":"14","title":"Larissa Fair","image":"larissa14.png"},{"id":"13","title":"Larissa Fair","image":"larissa13.png"},{"id":"12","title":"AEL FC Arena","image":"larissa12.png"},{"id":"11","title":"AEL FC Arena","image":"larissa11.png"},{"id":"10","title":"Alcazar Park","image":"larissa10.png"},{"id":"9","title":"Alcazar Park","image":"larissa9.png"},{"id":"8","title":"Church","image":"larissa8.png"},{"id":"7","title":"Church","image":"larissa7.png"},{"id":"6","title":"Old trains","image":"larissa6.png"},{"id":"5","title":"Old trains","image":"larissa5.png"},{"id":"4","title":"Munipality Park","image":"larissa4.png"},{"id":"3","title":"Munipality Park","image":"larissa3.png"},{"id":"2","title":"Ancient Theatre - Larissa","image":"larissa2.png"},{"id":"1","title":"Ancient Theatre - Larissa","image":"larissa1.png"}]
```

In order to display the data I need to exit the app and launch it again. Why is this happening? Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: I wonder what your problem has to do with a content provider.

Comment: So the first time the images have yet to be downloaded? And the second time the images are already downloaded?

Comment: @greenapps. Yes. The images need to be downloaded when you launch the app for the first time. And once you done that,you open the app again,to see them.

Comment: and there is nothing wrong with the content provider actually,as I did some junit on it too.

Comment: post your custom `ContentProvider` code, in your service call only provider methods in order to insert / update / delete your data

Comment: That's a bit confusing now. lol. Can you be more helpful on this one please?

Comment: your activity/fragment only talks to/listens from your content provider (CP), your service only talks to CP, the responsibility of CP is notify your activity/fragment if data has changed (it is done by loaders framework)

Comment: But i do that inside onCreateLoader. This method creates and returns a CursorLoader. CursorLoader has a constructor that takes all of the standard content provider query parameters, and will call the content provider on my behalf.

Comment: see [this](http://pastebin.com/gKPUPp03), notice `THIS IS IMPORTANT` comments

Comment: it is important to call notify after you insert data to CP. Loader must know what has just happened. Probably Your code is fine but as I said, You forget to notify. Try use after `getContentResolver().insert...` > `getContentResolver().notify...`. Refreshing adapter (I see it few lines down) will be handled by loader. There is no need to do it manually.

Comment: or you can check out my project on my github account. https://github.com/theo82/CustomProviderWithJson

Comment: @deadfish I have the notifyChanged() inside my content provider. You can check my above link to see the project.

Comment: @Theo I will check your repo tommorow and I give the answer.

Comment: @deadfish. Thank you.

Comment: tried my code? is not your `CursorLoader` reloaded?

Comment: @pskink. I haven't yet. I will look at it tomorrow. But if you want you can look at the link of my code described above. If you download it to your machine,run it and check the code,it would be easier to find the problem.

Comment: you dont have `notifyChange` in `remove` method and which is more important `setNotificationUri` in `query` method: see my code for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LoadManager doesn't handle Your changes in database because it doesn't have any connection to it. You must register observer to handle that stuff.

In Your `myCityProvider`, in `query(...)` method is missing method `setNotificationUri`. It should be set at the end.

Here is modified Your `query` method:

```
@Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        Cursor retCursor;

        switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            // All Flavors selected
            case MY_CITY: {
                retCursor = myCityDbHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(
                        MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.TABLE_MY_CITY,
                        projection,
                        selection,
                        selectionArgs,
                        null,
                        null,
                        sortOrder);
                break;
            }
            // Individual flavor based on Id selected
            case MY_CITY_WITH_ID: {
                retCursor = myCityDbHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(
                        MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.TABLE_MY_CITY,
                        projection,
                        MyCityContract.MyCityEntry._ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))},
                        null,
                        null,
                        sortOrder);
                break;
            }

            default: {
                // By default, we assume a bad URI
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
            }
        }

        if (retCursor != null) {
            retCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        }

        return retCursor;
    }
```

---

I've checked Your git repo and I think You should fix Your `MainActivityFragment`. You do everyting in `onCreateView` but You should do here all stuff related to view or just return inflated view. And after that, You can do the rest in `onViewCreated`.

You should do In this way:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(rootView, savedInstanceState);

        myCityAdpapter = new MyCityAdpapter(getActivity(), null, 0);
        mGridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.flavors_grid);
        mGridView.setAdapter(myCityAdpapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(CURSOR_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        switch (id) {
            case CURSOR_LOADER_ID:
                return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                        MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("id not handled!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        switch (loader.getId()) {
            case CURSOR_LOADER_ID:
                if (data == null || data.getCount() == 0) {
                    updateCityData();
                } else {
                    myCityAdpapter.swapCursor(data);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        myCityAdpapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
```

Thanks to that:

- if app opens, loader will load all what he have (can be 0 items) but if there aren't any items it will call service to download more and store in db
- if you add any data by service, onLoadFinished will be called again and refresh adapter

Comment: Omg! It is working now. You were right. I forgot to setNotificationUri. Many thanks sir!

Comment: Sorry again. I noticed something else. If I enter a new picture in my server,and run the app it is not shown in the gridview! In order to see that new picture,I need to go in settings -> MyApp -> Clear data,and run it again.lol. Why is this happening? Do is have to do something with the update method in the ContentProvider? Thanks.

Comment: or do I need to make a syncadapter?

Comment: Please read last sentence I wrote "if app opens, loader will load all what he have (can be 0 items) but if there aren't any items it will call service to download more and store in db". After first run You have already any items so `updateCityData` won't start. Try force it run after You call `swapCursor` and after that in `updateCityData` before parse images, remove all from database (or check what You have and insert only what is new).

Comment: Yes. It is better now. But when I delete a picture  from my server,that picture is still there. Please see my updated code in github. I also added a syncadapter.

Comment: I am not familiar with syncadapter. I never needed to use. Your problem with images should be categorized as another question.